# How do you increment an array by a register's value in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm supposed to translate C code into assembly and what's really stumping me is this statement:

```
for (uint i = 1 ; i <= k ; i++)
    b [i]= 0;
```

I've got the rest of the condition of the for loop, but the actual statement in the for loop is troubling me. The only solution I've come up with is:

```
sw $zero, $t2($a1) # $a1 is the base address of the array and $t2 is i
```

But I'm sure this is not allowed and is wrong for the reason that I would need to multiply the value assigned to `i` by 4 to effectively reach the next index of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not allowed to do that. `sw` is an I-type instruction, so it takes two registers and a number literal.

To do this, you need to add 4 to `$a1` on each iteration of the loop. Remember that `$a1` contains the address of the first element in the array, so by incrementing this by the size of a pointer (4 bytes), you move the pointer further down the array.